# - Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "STDIN": Secret in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Secret: json:

Tags: mysql, deployment, kubernetes-secrets

I have the following `yaml` file creates a `Kubernetes secret` for `mysql` database.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-secret
  key: MYSQL_KEY
type: Opaque
data:  
  mysql-root-password: 11111
  mysql-user: a
  mysql-password: 11111
```

But when I try to deploy it I get the following error:

```
 - Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "STDIN": Secret in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Secret: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field Secret.data of type []uint8
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

`EDIT`: The reason why do I added `key: MY_SQL` field is because previously I could deploy `mysql` on `Kubernetes` cluster using the secret ke created by this command:

```
kubectl create secret generic mysql-secret --from-literal MYSQL_KEY=11111
```

And I wanted to produce the exact same output. I also need a `MY_SQL` key to be able to connect to this pod from inside another pods like `auth` pod that you can see it's `deployment` file below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: auth
          env:
            - name: MYSQL_URI
              value: 'mysql://auth-mysql-srv:3306/users_auth'
            - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-secret
                  key: MYSQL_KEY
```

Comment: is your data section only an example or are you really passing them as they are? 
[ mysql-root-password: 11111 ad etc.. ] and currently they are also numbers.
This is something to focus : "json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field Secret.data"
Moreover in data, you can only pass base64 encoded string values.

Comment: @ishuar: Actually I have a `mysql` installed locally that works with either `mysql -u root -p11111` or `mysql -u a -p11111` and I wanted to create such a passwords and users for the `mysql pod` as well. But I don't know how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment already, your `.yaml` is not a valid file for secret `kind`. You are passing incorrect values to the `data` section.

While creating secrets via YAML you have to explicitly pass base64 encoded strings it does not automatically do that like in the CLI command.

- Number types values `111111` are not accepted or in more general only base64 encoded string values are acceptable.
- `metadata.key` is an unknown field in the secret kind. You have to remove it not sure what exactly you want to achieve with it so can't recommend something anything other than removing it.

### Fix For Data Section.

First, you have to encode your values in base64 and then to have you use those base64 encoded values.

```bash
➜  secrets-error git:(main) ✗ echo "11111" | base64 
MTExMTEK
➜  secrets-error git:(main) ✗ echo "a" | base64    
YQo=
```

- Update `.yaml` file with correct data values and remove `metadata.key`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  mysql-root-password: MTExMTEK
  mysql-user: YQo=
  mysql-password: MTExMTEK
```

### Edited

you should have base64 binary installed on your machine to use my above-mentioned commands otherwise can also use `kubectl` or any online base64 converter to do it for you.

- With `kubectl` commands.

```bash
## To Just generate the Yaml file if only want to create secret via YAML.
kubectl create secret generic mysql-secret --from-literal=mysql-root-password="111111" --from-literal=mysql-password="111111" --from-literal=mysql-user="a"  -o yaml --dry-run=client
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Please also read the added edit part to my quesion.

Comment: In summary, I don't know if I remove `key: MY_SQL` how can I fill out the `key:` property in the other `deployment` files like `auth` that I added it's code to my question.

Comment: I get such an error without the `key` : `- deployment/mysql: container mysql in error: &ContainerStateWaiting{Reason:CreateContainerConfigError,Message:couldn't find key MYSQL_KEY in Secret default/mysql-secret,}`

Comment: Honestly this is beyond the real question scope but i believe what you want to do is to set up env variable "MYSQL_KEY" in the pod via secretKeyRef then just use name: MYSQL_KEY and value: whateverValue. If this does not help. I would request you to open another question to maintain the question context.